# add transition to display using TailwindCSS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have been working on the following example. [using TailwindCSS]

```
 <div className="flex flex-col w-[250px] p-4 bg-white/5 bg-opacity-80 backdrop-blur animate-slideup rounded-lg cursor-pointer">
      <div className="relative w-full  h-56 group ">
        <div
          className={`absolute inset-0 justify-center items-center bg-black  bg-opacity-50 group-hover:flex
      ${
        activeSong?.title === song.title
          ? ' flex bg-black bg-opacity-70'
          : 'hidden'
      }`}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

on hover the display of the inner box changes from absolute to flex I want to add some transition on hover

I tried adding `transition-all` class but nothing worked. I also tried increasing the delay. But nothing seems to happen.

Comment: It is intrinsic behavior of CSS that you cannot transition between the `display` CSS property.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, is there any other way I can do it @Wongjn

Comment: No, you cannot transition the `display` CSS property at all – it is intrinsic behavior of CSS.